# Desktop and URI Producing Character Artifact

Tags: java, primefaces, jsf-2

I have a Primefaces Commandlink that is giving me an artifact at the end of my mailto address. I am not sure where the '#' is coming from.

[image]

Here is the front-end code.

```
<p:commandLink value="Mail Video Link" action="#{requestBean.requestUtility.informationRequestLink()}" />
```

Here is the back-end action code.

```
    public void informationRequestLink() {
    String subject = "Video Link";
    String cc = "friend2@domain.com,friend3@domain.com";
    String requestLink = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SjeS6gtPq8E";
    String body
            = "Here is the link.\n"
            + requestLink + "\n\n"
            + "Watch at your leisure.";

    try {
        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();

        String mailURIString = String.format("?subject=%s&cc=%s&body=%s",
            subject, cc, body);
        URI mailURI = new URI("mailto", "user@domain.com", mailURIString);

        desktop.mail(mailURI);
    } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

[EDIT]

I can get rid of the '#' but then I get UTF-8 encoded spaces '+'.

[image]

```
        String subject = "Video Link";
    String cc = "friend2@domain.com,friend3@domain.com";
    String requestLink = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SjeS6gtPq8E";
    String body
            = "Here is the link.\n"
            + requestLink + "\n\n"
            + "Watch at your leisure.";

    try {
        Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();

        String mailURIString = String.format("mailto:%s?subject=%s&cc=%s&body=%s",
                "friend1@domain.com", subject.replaceAll(" ", "%20"), cc, URLEncoder.encode(body, "UTF-8"));
        URI mailURI = URI.create(mailURIString);

        desktop.mail(mailURI);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: So if you use a `p:commandLink` with ajax you don't have this? Or without ajax? Or from a unit-test without jsf?

Comment: The '#' character is still there for both ajax="true" and ajax="false".

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `h:commandLink` ;-) to exclude it is PF related

Comment: And **please try in a unit test** 99,9% certain not jsf or primefaces related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash-character is appended by the constructor you're using.
Have a look at the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#URI(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

> `public URI(String scheme, String ssp, String fragment) throws URISyntaxException`
>
> [...]
>
> Finally, if a fragment is given then a hash character ('#') is appended to the string, followed by the fragment. Any character that is not a legal URI character is quoted.

You should use the appropriate constructor of `URI`; refer to the documentation. To me, it seems your third argument is more a `query` than a `fragment`.

Comment: Updated the constructor to use it properly.
Original constructor = URI mailURI = new URI("mailto", "user@domain.com", mailURIString);
New constructor = URI mailURI = new URI("mailto", mailURIString, "");
Bingo!